# bad string in dynamic sql and context info

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, context-info

This is so strange! The following code is a t-sql.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cinfo VARBINARY(128) = CAST('aud:83/53784862/1' AS VARBINARY(128));
    DECLARE @csinfo VARCHAR(128) = CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARCHAR(128));
    SET @csinfo = '<root><value>' + REPLACE(RIGHT(@cinfo, LEN(@cinfo) - 4), '/', '</value><value>') + '</value></root>';
    PRINT @csinfo
    SET CONTEXT_INFO @cinfo;
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '
        DECLARE @cinfo VARCHAR(128) = CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARCHAR(128));
        DECLARE @csinfo VARCHAR(512) = ''<root><value>'' + REPLACE(RIGHT(@cinfo, LEN(@cinfo) - 4), ''/'', ''</value><value>'') + ''</value></root>'';
        PRINT @csinfo
    '
    EXEC(@sql)
END
```

This is the output:

```
<root><value>83</value><value>53784862</value><value>1</value></root>
<root><value>83</value><value>53784862</value><value>1
```

Why `</value></root>` is not appended!

Comment: The version of sql-server is 2012

Comment: its appended.. Just with some spaces. Observe in the right corner side of SSMS

Comment: Agreed, I get `</value></root>` after a bunch of NULL characters.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza no, its not appended. because the sql server said the latter string is not a valid xml.

Comment: @Larnu you mean there is a null character at the end of the latter string, so no string can be appended to it?

Comment: A NULL character (`CHAR(0)`), and a string of the value `NULL` are different.

Comment: @Larnu I know the meaning of null character. The current problem is that no string can be appended to `REPLACE(RIGHT(@cinfo, LEN(@cinfo) - 4), ''/'', ''</value><value>'')` in the dynamic sql. But the same code works in the static environment.

Comment: What do you mean a "static" environment? If you run that SQL outside of dynamic SQL you get the same result (with a load a NULL characters at the end).

Comment: just see the question, the first output is out of dynamic sql, and this is what I want.

Comment: The output from the dynamic SQL is no different to if you run it non-dynamically. They both have a load of NULL characters before the end tag. This is not a surprise, and the value of `CONTEXT_INFO` ends with a lot of 0's, which would convert into a NULL character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
DECLARE @cinfo VARCHAR(128) = REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARCHAR(128)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS VARCHAR(128)), CHAR(0), '');
```

this will repair the string convert from `CONTEXT_INFO()`.